# How could I enforce model data in memory to accelerate the query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some models, the data is small but frequently used and also changing several times a week.

Currently, I'm using the cache to accelerate the response (by putting them into memory)

However, it will be a sort of buggy,

Once I forget to change the `cache name` like `"model_#{self.to_s}_#{__callee__}_#{city}-2016-01-28"`

How could I enable the access models operations in memory (like put them into Redis, or some memory based DB, only for some special models)

I'm using mongoDB currently.

Thanks

```
class AA
  include Mongoid::Document
  def self.get_country(city_or_airport_name)
    any_of({airport: /.*#{city_or_airport_name}.*/i},
       {city: /.*#{city_or_airport_name}.*/i}).to_a.first["country"]
  end

  def self.get_airports(city)
    Rails.cache.fetch("model_#{self.to_s}_#{__callee__}_#{city}-2016-01-28") do
      where(city: city).to_a.collect{|i| i.airport}
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I use memcached in front of some SQL tables that don't change too often, but get hit a few times per second. Redis will do too. I also have tables which change rarely (once a week or so), when there is under 100-500k of data i dump it to a JSON file via crontab or upon change, then preload at application boot, but this slows down booting and may cause trouble later if the table/set grows.